# htaccess & WebsitePanel 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've a problem running my website at a server with WebsitePanel (1.2.1) and Helicon Ape module installed to allow the use of the htaccess file.

I enabled the Helicon Ape module at the website properties panel but the htaccess doesn't works, the server give me an 404 error.

Someone knows where is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok,

I found the problem. The server owner doesn't had the license in order. They had the trial license and this period expired days ago.

This is all.